# Avoid overriding all abstract methods in Java

Tags: java, overriding, abstract-class

I wonder if there is any way to avoid unnecessary methods from implemented interface or other class.
Let say that I have simple class implementing  `MouseListener`, when actually I need only one method `mousePressed( MouseEvent e)` to override. However, in that case I also have to override every other method from interface but keep them empty like that:

```
public void mouseExited( MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseClicked( MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseReleased( MouseEvent e) {}
public void mouseEntered( MouseEvent e) {}
```

Is there any tricky solution to override only method I really need even when the others are abstract in interface/superclass and still keep my class as non-abstract?

Answer (score 8):

Extend `MouseAdapter`. It implements `MouseListener` by doing nothing for every method. So you can just override the one that you want.

Comment: But what if I need to extend some other class and implement a couple of interfaces?

Comment: You can implement an infinite number of interfaces but you can only inherit from one class. So you have to make a choice.

Comment: On top of that, if you want to be able to do this for any other interface you can make a dummy class that implements all of the interface methods (and does nothing with them) and then extend that class. I wouldn't recommend doing so though.

Comment: Maybe the MouseListener is trying to do too much if it needs to extend a class other than MouseAdapter and implement a couple of interfaces. Remember you can give it a constructor that takes a reference parameter, so it have have a has-a relationship to some other object.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of JB Nizet is good but by the way why it is a problem ? with modern IDE like Eclipse you can add all methods to implement with just one click (source > override/implement method).
If you use an adapter it's practical but you can't extend another class than the adapter.

Comment: I was only wondering how to avoid unnecessary code whom I didn't use at all, but need to place in my classes.